# Insert hyphen when regex group is not null or empty

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a numeric code which varies in length from 6-11 digits

which is separated by hyphen after each 3 digits

possible combinations

123-456

123-456-78

123-456-7890

So, here I am trying to convert the user entered code to this format even when entered with spaces and hyphens in the middle.

For Ex:

```
    123 456-7 -> 123-456-7

    123456 789 -> 123-456-789

    123456 -> 123-456
```

Valid user input format is 3digits[space or hyphen]3digits[space or hyphen]0to5digits

I tried it like this

```
code.replace(/^(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{0,5})$/,'$1-$2-$3');
```

But when there are only 6 digits there is a hyphen(-) at the end of the number which is not desired.

```
  123-456-
```

Could anybody help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: Should it possibly be 6-10 digits?

Comment: @ClasG Its minimum of 6 and maximum of 11

Comment: 3+3+4 makes 10 to me... Where's the eleventh digit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will do it for you - replace

```
^(\d{3})[ -]?()|(\d{3})[ -]?(\d{1,5})
```

with

```
$1$3-$2$4
```

It has two alternations.

1. `^(\d{3})[ -]?()` matches start of line and then captures the first group of three digits ($1), then optionally followed by a space or an hyphen. Finally it captures an empty group ($2).
2. `(\d{3})[ -]?(\d{1,5})` matches, and captures ($3), three digits, optionally followed by a space or an hyphen. Then it matches and captures (($4)) the remaining 1-5 digits if they're present.

Since the global flag is set it will make one or two *iterations* for each sequence of digits. The first will match the first alternation, capturing the first three digits into group 1. Group 2 will be empty.

For the second iteration the first match have matched the first three digits, so this time the second alternation will match and capture the next three digits into group 3 and then the remaining into group 4.

Note! If there only are three digits left after the first match, none of the alternations will match, leaving the last three digits as is.

So at the first *iteration* group 1 are digits 123. group 2, 3 and 4 are empty. The second iteration group 1 and two are empty, group 3 are the digits 456 and group 4 are digit 7-11.

This gives the first replace $1 = `123-` plus nothing, and the second `456-67...`.

There's no *syntax checking* in this though. It assumes the digits has been entered as you stated they would.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zqGdD9/4).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is probably to just do this with a second `replace`:

```
code.replace(/^(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{0,4})$/,'$1-$2-$3')
    .replace(/-$/, '');
```

This is chaining a second replace function, which says "replace a `-` at the end of the string with an empty string". Or in other words, "if the last character of the string is `-` then delete it.

I find this approach more intuitive than trying to fit this logic all into a `replace` command, but this is also possible:

```
code.replace(
  /^(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{0,4})$/,
  '$1-$2' + ($3 == null ? '' : '-') + $3
)
```

I think it's less obvious at a glance what this code i doing, but the net result is the same. If there was no `$3` matched (i.e. your sting only contained 6 digits), then do not include the final `-` in the replacement.

Comment: Yes this definitely works, Thank you. But I am just curious how it can be done.

Comment: Nicely done Tom, would you be able to add a quick explanation as to where the OP went wrong and what your code does to resolve it?